# Security Manager Tomcat 7 in Raspberry Debian Squeeze

Tags: java, tomcat

I cannot login in my Security Manager for Tomcat 7.0.42

i've added this role into tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="user" password="password" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

but when I try to do the login it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you restart Tomcat after making the change?

Comment: Make sure that your roles and users are not commented out in tomcat-users.xml. They are commented out by default and I've seen people overlook that a few times.

Comment: Yes i take off comments, and I've restarted tomcat but it still does not work

Comment: Make sure that the manager application has been deployed in the directory {tomcat-home}/webapps/manager.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error given by tomcat gives you the solution of this problem.

The default configuration are not good to work. 
They must the modified.

Open the tomcat file for user configucation:

```
nano /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml
```

You have to create a role named *manager-gui*. Add thoses lines.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

Then you need to restart your tomcat service.

```
sudo /bin/su - tomcat -c /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/shutdown.sh
```

Verify that the process is shutdown with:

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

Then restart tomcat

```
sudo /bin/su - tomcat -c /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh
```

You are GOOD to go ! I hope..